# Align table header to left of table and center everything at the same time

Tags: html, css

I created a html table with a header and I want to align the elements columnwise vertically so they start at the same position and aligned in the center at the same time. I found a way to align and center them but once centered they don´t start at the same line anymore.

I want it to look like:

[image]

My code is:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


th{
  text-align:left;
}

.flex-container>div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.h1_rentings {
  text-align:center
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="h1_rentings">Buchungen</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="center">
      <tr class="header_row">
        <th>Ladestand</th>
        <th>Nötige Distanz</th>
        <th>Beginn</th>
        <th>Ende</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="white_row">
        <td>60</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>02.04.2020 08:00</td>
        <td>02.04.2020 12:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>08.04.2020 11:45</td>
        <td>08.04.2020 19:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="white_row">
        <td>33</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>12.04.2020 09:00</td>
        <td>12.04.2020 16:15</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found out that I can use `align-items:left` to make it align at one line but it does not center them anymore. I tried to put it into a div as well and give the div some margin without success.

I tried to change to `text-align:left;` for the h1, but this makes it too far off and also tried with grid layout. with grid it started a little bit too far left as well.

is there a possibility with `position` to fix this? As far as I can see it it works more parent to child and not child to child. I even tried with list for the elements but just got more buggy actually. I was not able to align the content at all. I guess list is really more for text.

Any idea on this is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: From running your script, only the `<h1>` is not left aligned as your image, is this what you want to change to make it left aligned?

Comment: yes so that the h1 starts at the beginning of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would center the container and set `width: fit-content;`.
Then, the heading should be aligned to the left (of its container).

```css
.flex-container {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


th{
  text-align:left;
}

.flex-container>div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.h1_rentings {
  text-align:left
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <h1 class="h1_rentings">Buchungen</h1>
    <table class="center">
      <tr class="header_row">
        <th>Ladestand</th>
        <th>Nötige Distanz</th>
        <th>Beginn</th>
        <th>Ende</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="white_row">
        <td>60</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>02.04.2020 08:00</td>
        <td>02.04.2020 12:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>08.04.2020 11:45</td>
        <td>08.04.2020 19:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="white_row">
        <td>33</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>12.04.2020 09:00</td>
        <td>12.04.2020 16:15</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it quite clear! I think you can delete `.h1_rentings { text-align:left }` since it is not needed. so `width: fit-content;` makes it responsive to margin?

Comment: Yes I kept it so it's clearer. But you are right

Answer (score 2):

Remove `CSS` Check Now

```css
.flex-container {
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
th{
  text-align:left;
}
table.center {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="h1_rentings">Buchungen</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="center">
      <tr class="header_row">
        <th>Ladestand</th>
        <th>Nötige Distanz</th>
        <th>Beginn</th>
        <th>Ende</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="white_row">
        <td>60</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>02.04.2020 08:00</td>
        <td>02.04.2020 12:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>08.04.2020 11:45</td>
        <td>08.04.2020 19:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="white_row">
        <td>33</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>12.04.2020 09:00</td>
        <td>12.04.2020 16:15</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is it important to set `max-width:500px;`?